# pandas finding max date across 10 year span

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a datetime index across 10 years
measuring a stocks open price daily.

here is some example data from that set:

```
   date          stock price open

2005-01-01          5.5
2005-01-02          6.5
2005-01-03          6.3
2005-01-04          6
...
2006-01-01          8
2006-01-02          8.5
...
2015-01-01          19.5
2015-01-02          20
```

every date for 10 years is an observed. (Excluding leap years)

What i want is to produce a column showing the maximum stock price open 
value across all ten years for each specific day.

This is looking at the max across the 10 year span, but the year can
be given in the date column, i just need the stock value.

like so:

```
 date      max stock price open (over decade)

01-01          19.5
01-02          20
01-03          21
01-04          25
...
03-01          22
03-02          19
...
12-01         27
12-02         26
...
```

any ideas? I'm confused on how to group by date without specifying the specific year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.read_csv('stocks.txt', sep=r"[ ]{2,}")

df['date'] = df['date'].str[5:]

print(df)
    date    stock price open
0   01-01   5.5
1   01-02   6.5
2   01-03   6.3
3   01-04   6.0
4   01-01   8.0
5   01-02   8.5
6   01-01   19.5
7   01-02   20.0

df_gb = df['stock price open'].groupby([df['date']]).max()

print(df_gb)

date
01-01    19.5
01-02    20.0
01-03     6.3
01-04     6.0
```

To get the max year in a new df you can do this:

```
df_gb_dict = df_gb.to_dict()

max_year_list = []

for idx, row in df.iterrows():
    for k, v in df_gb_dict.items():
        if k == row['date_2'] and v == row['stock price open']:
            print(k, v, idx)
            max_year_list.append([k, v, idx])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(max_year_list, columns=['month_day', 'spo_high', 'date'])

new_df.sort_values(by='month_day', inplace=True)

new_df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(new_df)

    month_day   spo_high    date
0   01-01   19.5    2015-01-01
1   01-02   20.0    2015-01-02
2   01-03   6.3     2005-01-03
3   01-04   6.0     2005-01-04
```

Answer (score 0):

### This Assumes decade = 200-2009, 2010-2019, etc, but you can change it by changing the decade_variance calculation below...

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
```

### Import the Dataframe

```
decade = pd.read_excel('C:/stackoverflow/decade.xlsx', index_col='Date')
```

### Create a column to split the data by decade

```
decade_variance = decade.index.year//10*10 - decade.index.year
decade['Date_decade'] = decade.index.copy()

for i in range(len(decade.index)):
    decade['Date_decade'][i]  = decade['Date_decade'][i] + pd.DateOffset(years=decade_variance[i])
```

### Retain only the largest prices in the decade by month-day, and sort the data by date

```
decade.sort_values(by=['Date_decade','stock Price Open'], ascending=[True, False], inplace=True)
decade.drop_duplicates(subset=['Date_decade'],inplace=True)
decade['Date_decade'] = decade['Date_decade'].dt.year
```

### Reset the index to show the month-day and drop the year ( this will change the index from a DatetimeIndex to a string index)

```
decade['month-day'] = decade.index.copy()
decade['month-day']  = decade['month-day'].apply(lambda x: pd.datetime.strftime(x, "%m-%d"))
decade.set_index('month-day', inplace=True)

decade
          stock Price Open  Date_decade
month-day       
01-01     8.0               2000
01-02     8.5               2000
01-03     6.3               2000
01-04     6.0               2000
01-01     19.5              2010
01-02     20.0              2010
```